# How long can an Apple Watch stay without an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, health.app, watchos

I have an Apple Watch with is paired with my iPhone.

When my iPhone is out for maintenance, for how many days can I still use the Apple Watch without losing functionality and without losing the health monitoring data? i.e. when the phone will be back will I be able to dump all the data collected during the time?

Comment: I was able to use my Apple Watch for an entire week while my phone was broken and it seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no artificial limit imposed on how long the Apple Watch can remain away. When the Apple Watch reconnects to the iPhone, it will sync any data which is not on the iPhone as usual.

The Apple Watch has 8 GB of internal storage — whilst that won't *all* be available for Health data, Health only uses a very small amount of storage (~6 months for me has used 3.6 MB) so this isn't something to worry about.

Comment: I confirm that this is true, I got all my activities synched back after two weeks. The real pain is that when you don't have the phone you can not change time if you're traveling in to a different time zone :-(